# Gas usage higher when using the delete keyword

Tags: gas, gas-refund

I'm currently working on a marketplace demo for the consensys bootcamp, you can find my entire code [here](https://github.com/dev-bootcamp-2019/final-project-gretzke/blob/master/contracts/contracts/Marketplace.sol).

Stores inside the marketplace (which are structs) are stored inside a mapping and the keys pointing to the stores are stored in an array.
I have a function that removes a store and I wanted to test gas usage.

I have 2 different approaches:

- the first one just deletes the item id array and sets a bool flag to false
- the second approach just uses the delete keyword to delete the struct

.

```
/// @notice removes an existing store
/// @dev only callable by store owners, requires store to be active
/// @param _storeID ID of store to be removed
/// @return true on success, false on failure
function removeStore(bytes32 _storeID) public onlyStoreOwner returns(bool) {
    // storage pointers to store and store id list
    Store storage store = stores[msg.sender][_storeID];
    bytes32[] storage storeIdList = storeIdLists[msg.sender];

    // store has to be active in order to be removed
    require(store.active, "store currently not active");

    // copy last index of store id list to index of to be removed store and delete last item of array
    storeIdList[store.index] = storeIdList[storeIdList.length-1];
    storeIdList.length--;
    // remove items from store
    store.itemIdList.length = 0;
    store.active = false;

    emit RemovedStore(msg.sender, _storeID);
    return true;
}

function removeStore2(bytes32 _storeID) public onlyStoreOwner returns(bool) {
    // storage pointers to store and store id list
    Store storage store = stores[msg.sender][_storeID];
    bytes32[] storage storeIdList = storeIdLists[msg.sender];

    // store has to be active in order to be removed
    require(store.active, "store currently not active");

    // copy last index of store id list to index of to be removed store and delete last item of array
    storeIdList[store.index] = storeIdList[storeIdList.length-1];
    storeIdList.length--;
    // remove items from store
    delete stores[msg.sender][_storeID];

    emit RemovedStore(msg.sender, _storeID);
    return true;
}
```

when I test the gas usage of both functions I generate a new store with the name "test" and the description "test". The item id list is empty and the bool flag gets set to true.

the removeStore function has a transaction cost of 26641 gas

[image: removeStore info]

as expected, the bool flag is set to false, everything else stays.

[image: removeStore variables]

now the removeStore2 function has a transaction cost of 37230 gas

[image: removeStore2 info]

again, everything gets deleted as expected

[image: removeStore2 variables]

Now to my question:

why does the second function consume more gas? the delete keyword sets 2 more non-zero storages to zero. shouldn't there be a gas refund? The transactions were tested with ganache-cli and the remix javascript vm.

Comment: Have a look over here? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15573/why-does-delete-increase-overall-gas-cost

Comment: I don't see how that question relates. The issue in that code was doing the same deletion work twice.

Comment: yeah now that I looked into the other issue I don't see why it costs more gas.. I think it might have to do something with deleting arrays. check this code out in remix: https://gist.github.com/gretzke/f1a1a8b6d662e2da4d137e79271422cf
the function deleting the larger array costs way more gas than the one removing the smaller array. I don't see the reason why, as I am setting more values, definitely from non-zero to zero

Comment: Working on an answer now. Give me 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Answered below. @RobHitchensB9lab it would be nice if you would unmark the wrong answer in that other question. I think people get misled by it frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr Once you've passed the point where the gas refunds exceed half the total gas used, doing more deletion actually costs more.**

If you build a minimal repro of the issue, you get to something like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Test {
    uint256 a = 1;
    uint256 b = 1;

    // gas cost ~= 13000
    function deleteOne() external {
        a = 0;
    }

    // gas cost ~= 15500    
    function deleteBoth() external {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }

    function reset() external {
        a = 1;
        b = 1;
    }
}
```

(When testing the two functions, be sure to `reset()` in between.)

This seems surprising at first because we mostly think of deleting (zeroing out storage) as having a negative gas cost, but it actually doesn't. Changing a value in storage from a non-zero value to a zero value has two effects on gas:

1. It costs 5,000 gas.
2. It adds 15,000 to the refund counter.

At the end of the transaction, the refund counter is used to subtract **up to half of the gas fees**.

So in the case of `deleteOne`:

- Base transaction fee is 21,000.
- Writing a zero to storage costs 5,000 gas.
- Changing a non-zero to a zero adds 15,000 to the refund counter.
- Total gas fees: 21,000+5,000 = 26,000.
- After refund: 26000 - min(26000/2, 15000) = 13000

In the case of `deleteBoth`:

- Base transaction fee is 21,000.
- Writing *two* zeros to storage costs 5,000*2=10,000 gas.
- Changing *two* non-zeros to zeros adds 15,000*2=30,000 to the refund counter.
- Total gas fees: 21,000+10,000 = 31,000.
- After refund: 31000 - min(31000/2, 30000) = 15500